# Swift - UITextField Search to add rows simultaneously to UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, search, uitextfield

I have this search function:

```
func searchFor(_ text: String) {
    for path in allPoemsPaths {
        for poem in Helper.getPoems(filePath: path) {
            if poem.body.applyingTransform(.stripDiacritics, reverse: false)!.contains(text) {
                searchResults.append(poem)

                resultsTable.beginUpdates()
                resultsTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: searchResults.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                resultsTable.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is called by UITextField delegate:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    searchResults.removeAll()
    resultsTable.reloadData()

    searchFor(" " + textField.text! + " ")

    return true
}
```

This search is carried through more than a hundred thousands of text files.

I want to dynamically/simultaneously adding a row once the searched text is found and being able to select it, even if search is not finished.

What I get is rows are added after search is done.

Any idea how?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

getPoems Function:

```
static func getPoems(filePath: String) -> [Poem] {

    // Extracting author name
    let array = filePath.components(separatedBy: "/").last!.components(separatedBy: "_")
    let arabicName = array[2]

    var poems = [Poem]()
    let poemsString = try! String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)

    // separate the file by '---' into array
    var poemsArray = poemsString.components(separatedBy: "---")

    // First item in the array is empty
    poemsArray.removeFirst()

    for poemItem in poemsArray {
        var poem = Poem()

        if let poemBody = getXmlItem("poem", from: poemItem) {
            poem.body = poemBody
        } else {
            continue
        }

        // Extract title
        if let indexOfSlash = poem.body.index(of: "/") {
            poem.title = String(poem.body[..<indexOfSlash])
        } else {
            continue
        }

        if let i = getXmlItem("index", from: poemItem) {
            poem.index = Int(i) ?? 0
        }
        if let n = getXmlItem("versesNumber", from: poemItem) {
            poem.numberOfVerses = Int(n) ?? 0
        }
        poem.bahr = getXmlItem("bahr", from: poemItem) ?? " "

        poem.qafiya = getXmlItem("qafiya", from: poemItem) ?? " "

        poem.author = arabicName

        poems.append(poem)
    }

    return poems
}
```

Comment: You have to change your `getPoems` method to call the completion whenever the searched text is found. Can you show your `getPoems` method that is inside `Helper` class?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you check which thread is the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` call running on? and at what time the call is first invoked?

Comment: All my code is on the main thread. I do not know if some UIKit functions are supposed to run on other threads behind the scenes.

Comment: "what time the call is first invoked?"

Comment: I do not follow you. What do you mean by “what time”? It is called whenever the if statement is true.

Comment: How long does it take for `textFieldShouldReturn` for the loop to start running and how long does it take for it to end?

Comment: It takes about 0.04 sec for the first call of searchFor() func, then it takes 0.8-0.9 sec to come back. last duration depends on search input.

Comment: You mean the whole for loop to complete only takes 0.8 to 0.9 seconds?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forget to mention that I am testing the code on small number of files (just ~ 1400 text files). The whole project has more than hundred thousands of them.

Comment: Can you also check the time duration between the first time insert rows is called and the second time?

Comment: ~ 0.77 sec. Search dependent. Other row insertions calls have different timings.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178060/alis-problem

Comment: I am afraid can not. I must have 20+ reputations to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your method like this

```
func searchFor(_ text: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        for path in self.allPoemsPaths {
            for poem in Helper.getPoems(filePath: path) {
                if poem.body.applyingTransform(.stripDiacritics, reverse: false)!.contains(text) {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.searchResults.append(poem)
                        self.resultsTable.beginUpdates()
                        self.resultsTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.searchResults.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                        self.resultsTable.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does the most of job. Rows insertion is more smooth/flowing now and the calling function ends before the search function does. However I take the `searchResults.append()` inside the main thread because it gave me awkward results when I first run your code.

Comment: After trials, still for common words search the app seems to hang/unresponding until the search complete. I do not why.

Comment: @Ali_Habeeb Can you make small gif of what is happening and share it in the question?

Comment: @Ali_Habeeb Check the time it takes for the peom body to be transformed for one poem. If it takes a lot of time for common words you might want to show user progress or rethink the way you want to load data into the table.

Comment: Sure I will check. Thanks a lot Rakesha.